# How to upload image in database

Tags: java

I want to upload an image file and a pdf file in my back-end database. so that I can easily search or retrieve that image, pdf file. I want to write this in java language.

Comment: Use a [blob](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefblob.html) or  store the file somewhere on disk and store the path of the file in the database.

Comment: Please show some code that you've tried and where you are facing issues.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Table which have **BLOB** as a datatype
2. and then write simple JDBC program to insert image into database.
   do use of PrepareStatement like this:-

   all jdbc connections first
   then create fileinputstream object

   **FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("F:\img.jpg");**

   **PreparedStatement psmt = connection.prepareStatement("Insert into Table 
   values(?)");
   psmt.setBinaryStream(1,fis,fis.available());**

   **psmt.executeUpdate();**